# Syntax error compiling old Fortran code

Tags: debugging, fortran, fortran77, legacy-code

I'm trying to compile legacy Fortran code  with `fort77`. The command:

```
fort77 -c leg_code.f leg_code.o
```

fails with:

```
Error on line XXX: syntax error
```

Line `XXX` reads:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=10) TREE(2,MAXF)
```

where `MAXF`  is defined some lines above with:

```
  INTEGER MAXF, MAXC
  PARAMETER (MAXF=400, MAXC=20)
```

If I remove `(LEN=10)`, the code compiles with no issues.

Anyone know the reason for this error?

Comment: simply try :character(10) tree(2,maxf) or compile with a more modern fortran compiler (>= f90)

Comment: It looks like your code is at lesst Fortran 90 and you are using a Fortran 77 compiler.

Comment: It was a rather old code, so I thought I should compile with that. Didn't think if trying a more modern compiler. I tried with `gfortran` and it worked with no issues. Could either of you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it? Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the declaration statement

```
CHARACTER(LEN=10) TREE(2,MAXF)
```

is not valid in Fortran 77.  This form, declaring a rank-2 array of character of length 10, was introduced to standard Fortran in the Fortran 90 revision.

To declare such a variable in Fortran 77 the alternative form

```
CHARACTER*10 TREE(2,MAXF)
```

or

```
CHARACTER TREE(2,MAXF)*10
```

would be required.  Simply removing the `(len=10)`, as in

```
CHARACTER TREE(2,MAXF)
```

declares the variable to be an array of character of length 1, but this is valid in Fortran 77.

Comment: I don't remember being exposed to variant `CHARACTER TREE*10` before, nice to still learn something about f77

Comment: @aka.nice, the form `character x*10` is still in modern Fortran.  Indeed, it's still useful: it's the only way to override a character length declaration such as in `character(len=27) x, y*10, z` (much as one would see for overriding array size declarations `integer, dimension(12) :: a, b(5), c`).